# How do I create a link to a .exe file who has the same behavior that I get in windows?

Tags: wine, shortcuts

I have a World of Warcraft installation in my wine directory, and I want to place a link to it in the desktop. But when I create a link with the right mouse button menu, and place it in my desktop, it doesn't start. I'm a newbie here, so, forgive me if this is one basic function that I didn't have the braincells to discover

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to put "wine " without the quotes before the command in the command text box in the launcher.

==============================================

Go to Applications->Wine->Programs-> and right click on a program and select Copy to Desktop (if there is no program, try installing 7-zip from 7-zip.org by setup - it will show up).

Then right click on the program on the Desktop and select Properties. By looking at the command in the lancher you can easily see how to create new launchers to other .exe programs.

Comment: that's the problem. I don't have terminal skills, and my installation was copied directly from my windows partition, so I don't have it listed in wine. But my question isn't entirely wine-centric, because I've tried the same thing with a game called steelstorm, and it didn't worked either

Comment: All the explanations are graphical - when I say "command" I mean the text box Command: in the property window of the launcher, just like a shortcut in Windows.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that!

Comment: Still no good. It's not easy for me, to guess the proper line to use. The problem is that I can't even link linux executables to other parts of the system (desktop, in this case). What I ment is the behavior that drag-an-drop uses in windows when linking stuff around. I click in the .exe, put in my desktop, and voilá! This is what I want to do

Comment: First you create the link in the same folder as the executable, then you move the link to another place by drag and drop. IMHO there are Microsoft patents that Gnome or KDE can not infringe, one beeing direct shortcut drag and drop.